# How to import/export *individual* Rhythmbox playlists?

Tags: music, rhythmbox, playlists

I originally asked this question not realizing the functionality is built in, but not visible due to the "Alternative Toolbar Plugin"

I have a few playlists I'd like to transfer from one computer to another, how do I do this?

(This is with the alternative plugin toolbar).

Comment: Just try Musconv tools. Its a great way to transfer your playlists and favorites.

Answer (score 1):

This answer applies to Rhythmbox 3.4.3 with activated alternative toolbar plugin:

In the right top there is a toggle button with an ellipses icon (`...`) (between the search and menu icon). When activating this button, a menu (the file menu mentioned in the [previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1127651/932575)) appears above the playlist content: navigate to `Playlist -> Save to File...` to export the playlist.

Importing the playlist is also described in the [previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1127651/932575): Under the side bar navigate to `+ -> Load from File` to import the playlist.

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to disable the alternative toolbar plugin,
- Then restart Rhythmbox,
- Then, select the playlist you want to export,
- In the file menu, under playlists, save to file.

After transfering the exported file to a new system, if you have the alternative toolbar plugin installed, click the plus sign under your playlists, and select "load from file."